# Concat elements of tuple if contiguous lables are same

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, tuples

I have a list of tuples.

```
 [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c',1), ('d', 2), ('e',1)]`
```

The second element of tuple is its label. I want to concatenate the contiguous first elements whose labels are same.

By example, I want to convert
 `[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c',1), ('d', 2), ('e',1)]` to
 `[('abc',1),('d',2), ('e',1)]`

Comment: Why do you tag this both Haskell and Python?

Comment: I want to do this is functional way.

Comment: @user315971: but although Haskell is a functional language, you should not include it if you want to do it in Python in a functional way and vice versa.

Comment: Have you already tried any codes?

Comment: ok. removing it.

Comment: This should be pretty straight forward using `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick function to do this looping through the tuples and comparing each tuple to the label of the previous tuple and concatenating them if the labels match.

```
def parse_tuples(x):
    prev_tuple = list(x[0])
    parsed = []
    for i in x[1:]:
        if i[1] == prev_tuple[1]:
            prev_tuple[0] += i[0]
        else:
            parsed.append(tuple(prev_tuple))
            prev_tuple = list(i)
    parsed.append(tuple(prev_tuple))
    return parsed
```